Problem in the color of the shadow in mdframed package
When I write the following theorem with latex I hope to obtain a frame with a black shadow since the color in latex is black, but in the printing the color seems gray, this is my problem, I want to obtain the black color for the shadow. The code of latex is as follows.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}% 
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
%\usepackage{uncial}
%\usepackage[OT1,euler-digits,euler-hat-accent,OT1,T1]{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
%\colorlet{framecolor}{white}
%\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.6pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}
   \newcommand*{\QED}{\hfill\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}%Heron
   \usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\declaretheoremstyle[
headformat=\NAME~\NUMBER \NOTE,
    headpunct={.},
    headfont=\bfseries, 
    notefont=\slshape,  
    notebraces={(}{)},
    bodyfont=\itshape,
    headpunct={.},
    %postheadhook={\textcolor{black}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},
    %spacebelow=\parsep,
    %spaceabove=\parsep,
    mdframed={
    linecolor=black,linewidth=1.2pt,%
            %backgroundcolor=red!20, 
            linecolor=black, 
            innertopmargin=5pt,
            innerrightmargin=10pt,
            innerleftmargin=10pt,
            innerbottommargin=10pt,
            shadow=true,
            shadowcolor=Black,
            shadowsize=7pt
            } 
]{mystyle3}
\declaretheorem[name={Theorem}, style=mystyle3,numberwithin=section]{thm1}%numbering
\begin{document}
\begin{thm1}
dazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzdazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\end{thm1}
\end{document}


@AlainRemillard No I used declaretheoremstyle in setting

The first anwser of the linked post work in your case. Add \tikzset{every shadow/.style={opacity=1}} in your preambule the get the result you want.

Also, when posting code sample, try to make is as simple as possible by removing unnecessary packages (packages that are irrelevant to the problem)

As mentioned in the comments, always make your code as simple as possible by removing packages that are irrelevent for the problem. Have a look here for details.
By default, latex use an opacity of 0.5 on the shadow. This is what caused the gray color. To change this, use \tikzset{every shadow/.style={opacity=1}} in your preambule.
Here is the complete code that gives the desired result
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\declaretheoremstyle[
    mdframed={
            shadow=true,
            shadowcolor=Black,
            shadowsize=7pt
            } 
]{mystyle3}
\declaretheorem[name={Theorem}, style=mystyle3,numberwithin=section]{thm1}%numbering

\tikzset{every shadow/.style={opacity=1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm1}
dazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzdazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
\end{thm1}
\end{document}

